# Vue 3 / Composition API and inheritence

Tags: vuejs3

I am migrating to Vue3 from Vue2 and am trying to wrap my head around how to extend an existing vue component that has template, script and style sections in it. I have read about composables but I haven't seen an example that uses a combination of template/script/style sections. The only examples I see use a js/ts file which only contain the script section and then is usually inserted via useXYZ call.

Is this possible in Vue3? Do I have to use mixins or some plugin to make this happen?

```
// Foo.vue
<template>Some long template with lots of elements</template>
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
// Tons of functions and variables in here
export default Vue.extend({ [component "Foo" definition] })
</script>
<style>
  <!--Tons of CSS here -->
</style>
```

and the extended component:

```
import Foo from './Foo'

export default Foo.extend({ [extended component definition] })
```

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Actually, Vue3 does have [extends option](https://vuejs.org/api/options-composition.html#extends). But I don't see much benefit in using it. If you want to inherit functionalities, composable is enough. If you want to inherit CSS, you can write it in an individual and import it into the component you want

Comment: I still use [Mixins](https://vuejs.org/api/options-composition.html#mixins) with Vue 3 to reuse code in the components. It's very handy. But of course, you should prefer the `Composition API` for new code.

Comment: @Duannx The issue with using composables is that I also want the template stuff. Thanks for the extends link though